# How I can Download npm packages to use them into offline enviroment?

Tags: node.js, npm, download, offline

My development machine has no internet connection and I want to install gulp on my project:

```
npm install -g gulp
```

On my machine with internet connection I don't have right to install any piece of software (node or npm).

There is a way to download gulp package (like I do for nuget packages) and to install it to my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When installing `npm` modules globally, they are by default saved to

```
C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

You need to download the modules and manually place them in that folder, and make sure that the path has been added to `Path` environment variable on your computer.

Since you are not able to download them through `npm`, simply go to the `gulp` [github repository](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp), and place the content of that repository in a folder named `gulp`, in the path above.

Comment: I found some modules at `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules`. In Linux I found them at `/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules`

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install -g gulp
```

in your project directory use

```
npm link gulp
```

this will create shortcut of gulp module in node_modules so that you don't have to download it, make sure to upvote.